# How could I force EasyMDE to pass its content to the assigned "textarea"?

Tags: javascript, laravel-livewire

In the documentation, I found that using `forceSync: true` would do something similar, but that doesn't seem to be working for me.

When you write into it, it won't pass the stuff you wrote to the `textarea`.

This is how I load it up (alphinejs, livewire and laravel):

```
<div x-init="$nextTick(() => {
            let editor = new EasyMDE({
                element: $refs.editor,
                forceSync: true,
                toolbar: ['undo', 'redo', 'bold', 'italic', 'strikethrough', 'heading-smaller', 'heading-bigger', '|', 'code', 'quote', 'ordered-list', 'unordered-list', '|', 'link', 'horizontal-rule', '|', 'clean-block'],
                spellChecker: false
            });
            window.livewire.on('validationFailed', () => {
                let editor = new EasyMDE({
                    element: $refs.editor,
                    forceSync: true,
                    toolbar: ['undo', 'redo', 'bold', 'italic', 'strikethrough', 'heading-smaller', 'heading-bigger', '|', 'code', 'quote', 'ordered-list', 'unordered-list', '|', 'link', 'horizontal-rule', '|', 'clean-block'],
                    spellChecker: false
                });
            });
        })">
```

...and then below that
`<textarea x-ref="editor" x-data="{}" wire:model="content" name="content" id="content"...`

Whatever I do, the MDE editors content won't be passed to the textarea which fails the laravel/livewire validation.

Any idea?

Edit1: If I remove the EasyMDE creation from the `validationFailed` listener and just do `console.log(editor.value());`, it returns the actual value I wrote into the MDE editor.

So how come "forceSync" is not auto-passing its value to the textarea?